# Reducing battery usage on a SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, battery

I've finished developing a card game called **Up and Down the River** in SpriteKit. It is a fairly simple card game with a few animations such as the action of dealing and playing a card.

According to debugger tools, it is generally **Very High energy utilization** and the averages near **170 wakes per second**. (Shown below)

[image]

What is typical for a SpriteKit game? Should a simple card game be using this much energy? If not, what should I be looking for in order to reduce the energy usage?

***Note:*** This is being run on macOS, however the game is cross-platform (meaning iOS and macOS). I get similar results for running on an iOS device.

Comment: Using SpriteKit is already some kind of optimisation because this framework  is  already optimized to provide great performance and optimal energy efficiency. By the way, what is your number of draw calls (skView.showsDrawCount = true) and do you use atlases ? For start, i would recommend you to reduce the number of images per second.

Comment: `Draws` average between 20 and 30, `Nodes` start at 52 and increase by 4 each round until reaching a maximum of 88 and then decreasing by 4 back to 52. I am not using atlases, would they improve performance/energy efficiency?

Comment: You should use atlases (or at least to give it a try). That will improve your performance and probably reduce batery usage in some percent.

Answer (score 2):

When SpriteKit is running it is constantly updating the screen (usually at 60 frames per second).

If you do not need this high speed you can reduce it to 30 or 20 or lower frames per second by setting preferredFramesPerSecond on the SKView, see https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview

If your game is completely static while waiting for user input you can even set isPaused on the SKView to stop updates completely while you are waiting.

Comment: They actually changed this with iOS 10. SpriteKit is now only rendering when something is changing in the scene.